# Stripe API subscriptions

Tags: php, api, stripe-payments, subscriptions

I'm having a bit of a hard time updating a subscription with a new plan.
What I'm trying to do is the following:

Check if the subscription is still in trial mode. Get trial_end timestamp

1. If trial_end has not happened yet. Create new plan. Subscribe customer to new plan. Do not prorate anything. Carry the trial_end for the new plan. (In other words, don't charge the customer until after the trial period ends.)
2. If trial_end has already passed, create new plan, Sub customer to the new plan. Prorate the new plan. Carry the next billing date. (Meaning, again, don't charge the customer right now but add the prorated amount to the next invoice)

Here's the code I have so far:

```
//CREATE NEW PLAN
$plan = \Stripe\Plan::create(array(
      "id" => $usremail.'_'.time(),
      "name" => $usremail.'-'.time(),
      "currency" => "usd",
      "amount" => $totalamount,
      "interval" => "month",
    ));

$planid = $plan->id;
$proration_date = time();

//UPDATE SUBSCRIPTION
$subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::retrieve($subid);
$subscription->plan = $planid;
$subscription->proration_date = $proration_date;
$subscription->save();
```

When I do it this way, if the customer is in a trial subscription and signs up for a new plan, the subscription becomes active and the customer is charged right away the amount of the new plan.

I'm sure it is an easy thing, just can't figure it out.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

T

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to carry through the `trial_end` date from the previous Subscription, and include that in the update call you're making.

Comment: thx @floatingLomas I got that part working now. what if the trial period ended already? do I need to carry the billing date too? or does stripe take care of that with the update I posted above? Also, will they add the proration to the next billing date?

Comment: If the trial has ended, you can ignore the `trial_end` value.  If you're prorating, it'll end up with the same billing date as the one you're upgrading / downgrading from.

Comment: this is what I have so far: `$planid = $plan->id;
  $proration_date = time();
 
  $subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::retrieve($subid);
  $trial_end = $subscription->trial_end;
  $subscription->plan = $planid;
  
  if($trial_end<time()) {
   $subscription->proration_date = $proration_date;
  } else {
   $subscription->trial_end = $trial_end;
  }
  
  //$subscription->proration_date = $proration_date;
  $subscription->trial_end = $trial_end;
  $subscription->save();`

Comment: I was able to confirm that while in trial, carrying the trial_end works as intended. Still waiting to see if after trial has expired the proration is carried to the next original billing date.

Comment: my only concern is that I do not want the proration to be charged instantly

Comment: The proration will not be charged instantly unless you create an Invoice: https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/upgrading-downgrading#understanding-proration